# How to add a title beside a progress bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to achieve something like this

[image]

I used bootstrap and tried but it wasn't aligned i.e the title was slightly below the progress bar . 
Can anyone please help ?
Sorry if a similar question has been asked before.
Here is my code:

```
<div class="container"> 
    <p class="progress-label">Java <progress value="65" max="100" style="font-size: 80px; float: inherit;"> </p> 
</div> 
<div class="container"> 
    <p class="progress-label">Python <progress value="50" max="100" style="font-size: 80px"> </p> 
</div>
<div class="container">
     <p class="progress-label">C <progress value="50" max="100" style="font-size: 80px"> </p> 
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your code please.

Comment: <div class="container">
    <p class="progress-label">Java
    <progress value="65" max="100" style="font-size: 80px; float: inherit;">
    </p>
   </div>
   <div class="container">
    <p class="progress-label">Python
    <progress value="50" max="100" style="font-size: 80px">
    </p>
   </div>
   <div class="container">
    <p class="progress-label">C
    <progress value="50" max="100" style="font-size: 80px">
    </p>
   </div>

Comment: well, at least you don't have to bother adding another progress bar for "**HTML**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the grid Luke.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">Java</div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
          <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">Python</div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
          <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xd-3">
      <div class="col-xs-3">C</div>
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
            <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```